# Mailcore2 on Android hangs on MessageBuilder.setTo() when sending a message

Tags: android, mailcore2

I've got the Mailcore2 demo app working well.  But in trying to replicate the iOS sample code for sending an email on Android, I find that setting the list of To addresses on the MessageBuilder object hangs.  The call to `setFrom()` works fine.  You can see the iOS sample code here:

http://libmailcore.com/

Here's my code:

```
Address fromAddress = Address.addressWithDisplayName(MessagesSyncManager.singleton().displayName,
                MessagesSyncManager.singleton().user);
String stringToAddress = mEditTo.getText().toString();
Address toAddress = Address.addressWithMailbox(stringToAddress);
List<Address> toList = new ArrayList<Address>();
toList.add(toAddress);
Date now = new Date();
MessageBuilder builder = new MessageBuilder();
builder.header().setFrom(fromAddress);
builder.header().setTo(toList);
```

I've tried putting `setTo()` before `setFrom()`, but it still hangs.  In the debugger I've validated that `stringToAddress` is a correctly formatted email address, and that `toAddress` and `toList` get created correctly.  I've tried creating the To address using `Address.addressWithDisplayName()`, and the same thing happens.  When `setTo()` hangs, the emulator shows a message box that says "Unfortunately, MailExample has stopped."  I'm using Android Studio with the Nexus 5 API 21 x86 Android 5.0.2 emulator.

Comment: Does it happen with an empty list? I'm sure that's also an issue that needs to be fixed on mailcore.

Comment: Could you create file an issue on github? Thanks.

Comment: @Vance : can you share your android simple code to login from any id and send mail to fix email address ?